# Making a Square Animation

Tags: animation, geometry

Can I use mathematica to show an animation of

1. A 2x2 square
2. ..with its lower left quadrant colored
3. ..then with all of the square colored ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at `ListAnimate`, at `Rectangle`, etc? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this in Mathematica. Here's one example:

```
ListAnimate[{
  ArrayPlot[{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}],
  ArrayPlot[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}],
  ArrayPlot[{{1, 1}, {1, 1}}]
  }]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way:

```
frames = Table[
   Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], White, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 2}], Black,
      Rectangle[{0, 0}, p]}],
   {p, {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}}}];

ListAnimate[frames]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 5;
array = ConstantArray[0, {n, n}];

frames = Table[ArrayPlot[MapAt[Red &, array, {;; k, ;; k}],
      DataReversed -> True, Mesh -> All], {k, Range[0, n]}];

Export["arrayplot.gif", frames, "DisplayDurations" -> 1];
```

[image]

```
ListAnimate[frames]
```

[image]

Alternatively, using `Rectangle`s as in MelaGo's answer:

```
frames = Table[Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {k, k}]}, 
   Frame -> True, 
   FrameTicks -> False, PlotRange -> {{0, n}, {0, n}}, 
   GridLines -> Automatic, 
   Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}], {k, 0, n}];

ListAnimate @ frames
```

> same picture